# AttributeError: __exit__ when I try to mock out build in functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mox

I'm currently trying to mock out the open() built in method in Python for a test. However, I always end up getting a crash and this resulting message:

```
   File "/opt/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/result.py", line 187, in _exc_info_to_string
return _TextTestResult._exc_info_to_string(self, err, test)
 File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/unittest/result.py", line 164, in _exc_info_to_string
msgLines = traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb)
 File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 141, in format_exception
list = list + format_tb(tb, limit)
 File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 76, in format_tb
return format_list(extract_tb(tb, limit))
  File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 101, in extract_tb
line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
  File "/opt/home/venv/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 14, in getline
lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
 File "/opt/home/venv/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 40, in getlines
return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
 File "/opt/home/venv/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 127, in updatecache
with open(fullname, 'rU') as fp:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Here is my test code:

```
m = mox.Mox()
m.StubOutWithMock(__builtin__, 'open')
mock_file = m.CreateMock(__builtin__.file)

open(mox.IgnoreArg(), mox.IgnoreArg()).AndReturn(mock_file)
mock_file.write(mox.IgnoreArg()).MultipleTimes()
mock_file.close()

write_file_method()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__exit__` is the method that gets called when you try to close a file. Your mock file does not handle `mock_file.close()`, just `open()`. You'll need to mock the `close` method too.

---

Edit:

On second though, why do you want to mock `open`? AFAIK you shouldn't be doing that method. The method under test should take an open stream (instead of a filename, for instance). In production code, clients are responsible for opening a file (e.g. `pickle.dump`). In your tests, you pass in a `StringIO`, or a mock object that supports writing.

---

Edit 2:
I would split your method in two and test each bit separately.

- creating a file: check that prior to calling this method the file does not exist, and it does after that. One might argue such a one-line method isn't worth testing.
- writing to a file: see above. Create a `StringIO` and write to that, so your tests can then verify the correct thing has been written.

Comment: So I add a line saying m.StubOutWithMock(__builtin__, 'close')? I tried that but I get the same error, unless I put it in the wrong place (right after m.StubOut 'open')

Comment: The method I want to test makes a file and writes to it, so I don't pass in a file object or anything. I'm not sure how else to test it.

Comment: I don't think it's the `open` / `close` interface, at least not yet.  It looks like the problem is he's not mocking the context manager interface, ie `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  FYI, `__exit__` isn't called when closing the file, it's the other way around.  `__exit__` is called when exiting the context manager (`with` block), and it in turn calls `close`.  It also looks like the actual error in the test code is being swallowed by `nose`, because `nose` is trying to open a file to write an error to with the context manager syntax, but the patched `open` does not support it.

Comment: To mox out `__enter__` and `__exit__`, it is         `self.__mox.StubOutWithMock(__builtin__, '__enter__')` and such?

Comment: Those are methods on the object returned from `open`, not things from `__builtin__` directly.  Honestly though, I think you should try to find another approach.  You're going to break your test logging this way.  Maybe try writing a wrapper or something that patches locals/globals around your specific target function, so you don't impact other libraries relying on `open` outside of the code under test.

Comment: @SilasRay Thanks for the correction, you are right. I've updated my answer again :)